# Side-by-Side Boxplot Column Problems

Tags: r, csv, boxplot

I am trying to create a side-by-side box plot. I have my data in a csv file in two columns "Location" and "Chlorothalonil" and used the following code:

```
systems <- read.table("~/Desktop/2015_Pre_Nurse_Chloro.csv", 
                       header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=NULL)
boxplot(systems$Chlorothalonil ~ systems$Location, xlab="Site", 
        ylab="Chlorothalonil (ug/g)")
```

I keep getting the error

> "Error in model.frame.default(formula = systems$Chlorothalonil ~
>   systems$Location) :    invalid type (NULL) for variable
>   'systems$Chlorothalonil'

It seems like I need to specify the column titles somewhere...Any help?!

Comment: Please include sample data https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/786542

Comment: What's the result of `names(systems)`? Is 'Chlorothalonil' in there, spelled the same way with the same UppErCaSe letters?